# extract coefficients within R caret

Tags: r, r-caret, cross-validation, coefficients

```
library(caret)
data(iris)

train_control <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=10, repeats=10)
model <- train(Sepal.Length~Sepal.Width+Petal.Length+Petal.Width, data=iris, trControl=train_control, method="lm")
```

I can get the coefficients of the final selected model with model$finalModel$coefficients. Is there any way to get the coefficients for all models?

Comment: You think that the final coefficients _aren't_ used to generate the fitted values...?

Comment: Yes, my phrasing was ambiguous. I edited my question to clarify.

Comment: If you are asking if you can get the coefficients to all the models generated by resampling? If so, then the answer is no. There is no real way to do that right now.